# Can we declare and initialize a member variable from another member variable in same class

Tags: php, class, oop

i don't know much about `class` and their `member variables`. 
What my doubt is, can we declare and initialize a member variable from another member variable in same class?

like this

```
class newClass {
    private $variable1 = 'new1';
    private $variable2 = $variable1.'new2';
}
```

If can't, please help me find an solution for this.
Pardon me if this is a wrong question to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always initialize member variable in constructor. You can assign dynamic value in constructor.
Try this code:

```
<?php
class newClass {
    private $variable1 ;
    private $variable2;
    function __construct()
    {
      $this->variable1 = 'new1';
      $this->variable2 = $this->variable1.'new2';
    }
    function get_data()
    {
      echo "var1= ".$this->variable1;
      echo "<br>";
      echo "var2= ".$this->variable2;
    }
}
$obj = new newClass();
$obj->get_data();
```

Answer (score 4):

No. You can't do that.

What you could do instead is do the initialization in the constructor:

```
class Foo 
{
    private $a = 'something';
    private $b;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->b = $this->a . 'foobar';

    }
}
```

Buuuut, this would actually be a somewhat questionable practice, since it you should try to avoid doing any computation in the constructors, since you loose the ability to actually test that part of the logic (since constructor is always executed, you have no way to compare the before and after states).

A much better way would be to leave this logic in the getter-methods:

```
class Foo 
{
    const DEFAULT_VALUE = 'lorem ipsum';
    const DEFAULT_PREFIX = '_';

    private $bar;

    public function __construct(string $bar = self::DEFAULT_VALUE)  
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }


    public function getPrefixedBar(string $prefix = self::DEFAULT_PREFIX)
    {
        return $prefix .  $this->bar;
    }
}
```

With this code you will get:

```
$a = new Foo;
echo $a->getPrefixedBar(); // shows: '_lorem ipsum';
echo $a->getPrefixedBar('test '); // shows: 'test lorem ipsum';

$b = new Foo('xx');
echo $b->getPrefixedBar(); // shows: '_xx';
```